# How to add permission to user for one specific command

Tags: command-line, permissions, sudo

I have a Jenkins job which runs as Jenkins user. The script it runs need to delete one folder which owns www-data user. Jenkins user has not sudo privileges and I dont want to give it to him. The command looks like:

```
rm -rf /var/www/deploy-old
```

I don't want to add sudo privilege for rm command to Jenkins, but only for whole command including path. Is it possible or not?

Comment: Not possible, afaik. You may rather work with groups. Make that user member of the group that owns the /var/www directories, give the group read/write permissions and members of the group will need to changethese folders.

Comment: Ok, it seems like the only way. Thanks.